# Python inherit methods depending on condition in init

Tags: python, class, subclass

lets say I have two classes:

```py
class ImgClass():
    """
    A class based on an image
    """
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def i_am_an_img(self):
        ...


class PdfClass():
    """
    A class based on a pdf
    """
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def i_am_a_pdf(self):
        ...
```

I want to create a simple wrapper that goes something like this:

```py
class Wrapper():
    """
    The main wrapper that decides the bases class
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        file = Path(file)
        if file.suffix == '.jpeg':
            ImgClass.__init__(self)

        else:
            PdfClass.__init__(self)
```

but this does not give me the methods from the parent class (obviously, since I do not inherit). If I use inheritance (of both), I get all methods.
So I'm looking for a way to **init and inherit** just one of the two base classes during wrapper init. Is this possible?

Comment: The `Wrapper` class has a fixed set of classes it inherits from.  It can't be changed on an instance-by-instance basis.  What you want would require dynamically creating a new class (the class itself, not the instance) each time you want to change the base class.

Comment: You're probably better off writing a short function that takes `file`, and then returns and `ImgClass()` or `PdfClass()` instance. It's exactly like your init function, except that it isn't a class.

Comment: Yeah I was gravitating towards a function that exposes the right class. Seems to be the cleaner way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible in Python, and I even use that kind of "magic" in production code, but one thing much more mundane, and very acceptable is simply a factory function.

People won't yell at your code by using a factory function to instantiate your things:

```
class DocumentBase:
    """
    The main wrapper that decides the bases class
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        file = Path(file)


class ImgClass(DocumentBase):
    """
    A class based on an image
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__(file)
        ...
        # Image specific init code, if any. (otherwise, just suppress the __init__ method altogether)
        

    def i_am_an_img(self):
        ...


class PdfClass(DocumentBase):
    """
    A class based on a pdf
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        # Same as ImgClass.__init__
        ...

    def i_am_a_pdf(self):
        ...
        
        
def Wrapper(file):   # <- A function, not a class!
    """
    The main wrapper that decides the bases class
    """
    file = Path(file)
    if file.suffix == '.jpeg':
        instance = ImgClass(file)

    else:
        instance = PdfClass(file)
        
    return instance
```

However, what you want *is* possible - the `__new__` method in a class is the place which has to return an actual instance of your class. You can write your code so that this decision of what class to create is decided in `__new__`:

```
class DocumentBase:
    """
    The main wrapper that decides the bases class
    """
    
    _subclass_registry = {}
    suffixes = ()
    
    def __new__(cls, file):
        file = Path(file)
        target_cls = _subclass_registry.get(file.suffix.lower(), None)
        if not target_cls:
            raise TypeError("No class registered to handle {file.suffix} files")
        instance = super().__new__(target_cls)
        instance.file = file
        return instance

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        # called automatically whenever a subclass is created
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for suffix in cls.sufixes:
            _subclass_registry[suffix] = cls


class ImgClass(DocumentBase):
    """
    A class based on an image
    """
    suffixes = ("jpg", "jpeg", ...)
    def __init__(self, file):
        # Image specific init code, if any. (otherwise, just suppress the __init__ method altogether)
        

    def i_am_an_img(self):
        ...


class PdfClass(DocumentBase):
    """
    A class based on a pdf
    suffixes = ("pdf",)   # (the extra comma is neded to create a 1-element tuple)
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        # Same as ImgClass.__init__
        ...

    def i_am_a_pdf(self):
        ...
        
        
my_handler = DocumentBase(myfile)   # Will automatically be of a matching type
```

The disadvantages of this method are: it uses Python inner workings for object creation, and some people may find it strange, putting some burden on maintanence. Advantage: fully object oriented, your classes can be testes with `isinstance(DocumentBase)` (or `Wrapper` if you prefer that name).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I do like both versions however for the sake of clarity I think I prefer a simple function